# Comparing two absorption spectra as time series

Tags: time-series, paired-data, spectral-analysis

I would like to compare two absorption spectra ( or interferograms) and conclude whether between these two there are statistically significant differences at particular wavelength intervals. At the moment, I have data of two experiments that look like this:

```
    # A tibble: 6 x 5
      t     x1     y1     x2     y2
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 3999. 0.0124 0.0132 0.0122 0.0113
2 3998. 0.0125 0.0130 0.0122 0.0116
3 3997. 0.0122 0.0131 0.0122 0.0113
4 3996. 0.0121 0.0136 0.0122 0.0114
5 3995. 0.0124 0.0139 0.0122 0.0122
6 3994. 0.0125 0.0141 0.0122 0.0129
```

The first column represents the wavenumber, the x columns represent the absorbance of sample and the y columns represent the absorbance of irradiated sample ( before and after). I was wondering whether I could compare these data ( x and y) as time series and if so, what could be the method to quantify the differences, if any, between the samples before and after irradiation. Maybe it's already been done and there is somewhere some information as to how to compare the spectra if the wavenumber is interpreted as time ( x axis). I did the t test in R and in both experiments the null hypothesis could not be rejected, although for the second experiment (x2, y2) the p value was much lower than for the first.
If I average the x and y, and then plot both data, I see that there are visible differences at certain wavenumber intervals.
After averaging x and y I used IRISSeismic package ( in R) and function crossSpectrum, which gave me such an output:

```
   freq        spec1        spec2 coh        phase             Pxx             Pyy
1   0.0002666667 2.121935e+01 2.152532e+01   1  0.010220252 1.856693e+01+0i 1.883465e+01+0i
2   0.0005333333 7.011069e+00 6.869078e+00   1  0.008984730 6.134686e+00+0i 6.010443e+00+0i
3   0.0008000000 8.385363e+00 8.197039e+00   1  0.011999039 7.337193e+00+0i 7.172409e+00+0i
4   0.0010666667 7.483070e+00 7.272319e+00   1  0.015419031 6.547686e+00+0i 6.363279e+00+0i
5   0.0013333333 4.086251e+00 3.899095e+00   1  0.017551350 3.575469e+00+0i 3.411708e+00+0i
6   0.0016000000 1.537709e+00 1.405562e+00   1  0.008722742 1.345496e+00+0i 1.229867e+00+0i
```

For all data points the coh index is given as 1. But obviously that doesn't help me to determine, whether the difference is substantial between two data sets.
I tried to average data points between groups (x1, y1 and x2, y2) at each wave number and plotted the graph, it looks like the difference might be significant at certain wavenumber intervals. Maybe I could try to express one line ( averaged data points after irradiation of the sample) as a function of the other? But how?

Here is a project with similar experiments: https://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0103-50532015001202571 , for statistical analysis they use ANOVA and Tukey's test, but how do I do it for the vectored data?

I cannot find online anything. Here is something of the sort I am looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjKSfILE9nM He compares two spectra in Matlab, but he is using self made toolkit which I can not obtain. How can I do something like this in R? I've read something about modelling the data, but here, I don't have any variables just data of two spectra. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How you compare them depends in part on what scientifically meaningful ways there might be of comparing absorbances. Although in principle there's nothing wrong with viewing these as time series--they satisfy all the mathematical requirements--the usual methods to *analyze* economic and scientific times series are unlikely to be appropriate, because they adopt potentially unrealistic models.  (For instance, would you expect to see anything like "seasonality" or long-term trends?  I doubt it.) The measurement system is likely to afford hints concerning a good statistical model to use.

Comment: @whuber For example here: https://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0103-50532015001202571 I see something similar, and they use Anova test to test for significant difference. How this could be done with spectral data?

Comment: @whuber♦  Here I edited the post. I got an idea, that it would be possible to make estimations for x and y and then draw residual plots to see if they overlap, but in this case I have two data points for each wavenumber that correspond to x and y group, and I don't know if it's usually done in such experiments.

Comment: @whuber♦ Sorry, I mean estimation for groups x1,y1 and x2,y2 ( control and irradiated samples)